# Help trouble shoot audio driver

Tags: samsung, updates, audio, boot, linux

So my audio stopped working after the upgrade to android 10.
And I can not roll back to Android 9.
Phone Samsung Note 9.
Android 10.

Need help understanding the start-up process in android. Which file detects the chips, tells it which driver to load, and then logs the results after loading each driver.
Which log should I look in for failures i.e. If I run Sound Recorder and hit record? The app just hangs.
I cant click on stop. And can only kill it in notifications.

Like in Windows I can go to devise manager and see the list of drivers loaded and the status of each component. And if its failed it will say failed to load driver xyz.

If I have this info I can pinpoint which chip is acting up. I know the phone has one amp chip 98512 and one Audio Codec Chip. I want to know which IC is acting up or if its just a corrupted driver file.
I did Odin the factory Image onto the phone. Just to be sure.
Funny thing is Audio works in Blue Tooth but over the mic / speaker / ear phone jack all dead.

Comment: Have you considered that the mentioned app does not work because of new restrictions in Android 10? Especially apps like call recorders no longer work on Android 10+ therefore your recording app may also be affected. Make sure you are using a recorder app that is known to work on Android 10.

Comment: Yes, I have but when I say my audio is dead its dead. Can't get the speaker to work even in the diagnostic screen/safe mode / DND is off. The phone will not even ring. Playing movies with no audio. But if I cast or use Bluetooth I get audio. etc.

Comment: I found this info its a start. 
https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/logging/info

Comment: You could check kernel log via `dmesg` command. Drivers are in Linux usually located in the kernel and via dmesg you can see the kernel log.